Movie with brain attacking people on kitchen floor (pre 80s)
What older movie (pre-80s looking) has a brain that at some point is moving around on the floor trying to physically attack a couple?  It's been at least 15 years since I rented this movie from a place that no longer exists.
I think it was a kitchen floor (possibly with the brain covered in green slime and on a black and white checkered) where the brain was attacking.
It would definitely be classified as a B-movie nowadays.
Edit:
Unfortunately, I cannot recall any more details beyond the possibility of a staircase leading to the kitchen. The actors had no accents as I can recall so I'd guess it was an American movie, no subtitles or dubbing.  It was possibly rented as VHS, so maybe never made it as DVD. 

Hello and welcome. Any other plot details?

Please add additional details such as what language the movie was in, what country it took place in, any actors or actresses you recognize in it, etc. Any additional information you can supply will help your chances of getting an answer.

@theguest is probably correct, although it does sound very similar to Braindead (aka Dead Alive) (1992).  There are multiple scenes where a brain and it's spinal chord attack the main character in differrent parts of the house.  He finally kills it with a lawnmower in the kitchen, where there's a tiled floor.
I just picked one scene.  Not sure if its legal that this whole film is even on YouTube, but anyway...
WARNING: Not safe for work or children




It used to be my favourite zombie film.  Long before Peter Jackson was working with Hobbits... :-)

I actually own this film, not sure I've seen a bloodier one.  Romantic comedy!  I had totally forgotten how crazy this movie is and that there was a brain running about.
